# Type Casting Option in rust

Tags: rust, casting

How do I cast optional values in rust?

This is what I came up with, which does work, but I think there must be a more elegant way.

```rust
pub fn option_t_to_i32_option<T1, T2>(optional_val: Option<T1>) -> Option<T2>
where
    T2: From<T1>,
{
    return match optional_val {
        Some(val) => Some(T2::from(val)),
        None => None,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `map` `Into::into` for your constrains:

```rust
pub fn option_t_to_i32_option<T1, T2>(optional_val: Option<T1>) -> Option<T2>
where
    T2: From<T1>,
{
    optional_val.map(Into::into)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=76a68fc9ea979d0ac73d81304d427752)

As per your function name, maybe you would like to actually match the output type to `i32`:

```rust
pub fn option_t_to_i32_option<T1>(optional_val: Option<T1>) -> Option<i32>
where
    T1: Into<i32>,
{
    optional_val.map(Into::into)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b4e041d1b4d028d86b745835cca1165)

Btw, since this is a wrapper, you could rather use `_.map(Into::into)` wherever you need to go `Option<T> => Option<i32>` instead.

Comment: `map` is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!